# LEFT JOIN multiplying results PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, duplicates

**Before:**

```
--SELECT <columns>

Select cdr."Case Number"

    , cdr."Client Name"

    , cdr."SAI ID"

    , cdr."SAI Name"

    , Count(csr."Case Number") as "30DayAttempts"

    
    
--FROM <table>

From client_diagnosis_report as cdr

--JOIN <table> ON <conditions>

LEFT JOIN client_services_report as csr

ON cdr."Case Number" = csr."Case Number"



--WHERE <conditions>


WHERE csr."Person Contacted" in ('N' , 'B' , 'T' , 'C')

    AND csr."Service Date"::DATE > CURRENT_DATE - 365
    
    
--GROUP BY <columns>

GROUP BY cdr."Case Number"

,           cdr."Client Name"

,           cdr."SAI ID"

,           cdr."SAI Name"


--Having

--ORDER BY <columns>

ORDER BY cdr."Case Number" DESC

--LIMIT <row limit>
```

**After:**

```
--SELECT <columns>
Select cdr."Case Number"

    , cdr."Client Name"

    , cdr."SAI ID"

    , cdr."SAI Name"

    , Count(csr."Case Number") as "30DayAttempts"

    , crr."City"

    , crr."Address" 

    , crr."Home Phone" 

    
    
--FROM <table>

From client_diagnosis_report as cdr

--JOIN <table> ON <conditions>

    LEFT JOIN client_services_report as csr

        ON cdr."Case Number" = csr."Case Number"


    LEFT JOIN client_roster_report as crr

        ON cdr."Case Number" = crr."Client Case Number"


--WHERE <conditions>


WHERE csr."Person Contacted" in ('N' , 'B' , 'T' , 'C')

    AND csr."Service Date"::DATE > CURRENT_DATE - 365
    
    
--GROUP BY <columns>

GROUP BY cdr."Case Number"

,           cdr."Client Name"

,           cdr."SAI ID"

,           cdr."SAI Name"

,           crr."City"

,           crr."Address"

,           crr."Home Phone"

--Having

--ORDER BY <columns>

ORDER BY cdr."Case Number" DESC

--LIMIT <row limit>
```

**Result:**

Before Joining the client_roster_report the results are

```
Case Number | 30DayAttempts

1____________________34

2____________________11  
         
3____________________32

4____________________24

5____________________36
```

After Joining the client_roster_report the results are

```
1____________________68 (twice the original)

2____________________33 (three times the original)  
         
3____________________96 (three times the original)

4____________________72 (three times the original)

5____________________108 (three times the original)
```

I believe this is because the source data has duplicate rows equal to the amount it's multiplying by

```
source data

1

1

2

2

2

3

3

3

4

4

4

5

5

5
```

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening, either by only taking one result per case number or by removing duplicates before it's processed. really I'm open to any solutions.

Comment: 4 spaces before code to preserve formatting (or highlight the code block and click the `{}` in the editor).

Comment: Post a minimal data sample that can showcase your problem!

Comment: "...LEFT JOIN multiplying results PostgreSQL..." -- yes, that's how relational algebra works by definition.